# How to uninstall gem specific documentation post installation

Tags: ruby, engineyard

I just installed the engineyard gem and would like to know how to uninstall **all** ri / RDoc documentation of **engineyard** post installation

```
Is it safe to remove all files from the following folder c:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\doc

c:\Ruby192\bin>gem install engineyard

Welcome to Engine Yard!

Deploying for the first time? The Engine Yard Pandas want to help you!

Email pandas@engineyard.com with your questions or queries.
(Panda = 1. Polite Agent of Non-Destructive Assimilation; 2. Cute fluffy an
imal.)

We wish you every success with your business!

 - The Pandas

Successfully installed rest-client-1.6.3
Successfully installed highline-1.6.2
Successfully installed json_pure-1.5.3
Successfully installed escape-0.0.4
Successfully installed engineyard-serverside-adapter-1.4.1
Successfully installed net-ssh-2.1.4
Successfully installed engineyard-1.3.20
7 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for rest-client-1.6.3...
Installing ri documentation for highline-1.6.2...
Installing ri documentation for json_pure-1.5.3...
Installing ri documentation for escape-0.0.4...
Installing ri documentation for engineyard-serverside-adapter-1.4.1...
Installing ri documentation for net-ssh-2.1.4...
Installing ri documentation for engineyard-1.3.20...
Installing RDoc documentation for rest-client-1.6.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for highline-1.6.2...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had any experience with that gem yet, but I hope this can help you to track your rdoc and ri doc path.

```
gem env
```

on my Mac system, I found this path from **INSTALLATION DIRECTORY**

```
/opt/experiment/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/doc/
```

And when I `open` it (or `explore` in Windows) I saw some gems' rdoc/ri doc inside this path. Try to remove your gem's doc there. Let me know if it works, it's working here on my Mac.

Next time when you install rubygems but don't want ri/rdoc installed, remember to type this `--no-rdoc --no-ri` option when you do `gem install something`

As a reference comparison I'll just copy paste my `gem env` here

```
. gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-08-18 patchlevel 0) [i386-darwin9.8.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/experiment/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/experiment/ruby/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/experiment/ruby/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-darwin-9
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/experiment/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /Users/arie/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gemcutter_key" => "********************************"
     - :gem => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org
.
```

Update (7/28/2019): `--no-ri --no-rdoc` **no longer work** in *Rubygems* >= 2.0. Alternatively, you can use `--no-document` to omit documentation.